# Hibernate Criteria Restrictions.in combined with ilike

Tags: hibernate, criteria, restrictions

Is there a way to combine the

```
Restrictions.in(String, Collection<String>)
```

with

```
Restrictions.ilike(String, String)
```

The goal would be to provide a list of possible matches (like **in**) but to compare them with the **ilike** operator instead of a hard compare.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could build it by your own with the help of `org.hibernate.criterion.Disjunction`.

```
Disjunction or = Restrictions.disjunction();
or.add(Restrictions.ilike(String, String));
or.add(Restrictions.ilike(String, String));
or.add(Restrictions.ilike(String, String));
```